# How to shift a zero to the left

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

Let's say we have a one-byte number, `1`, in binary. The `1` an be shifted to the left by doing a `shl` instruction. For example, shifting it over two places so the number is `4`:

```
# 0000 0001
mov $0b1, %al
shl $2, %al
# 0000 0100
```

Is there a direct way to shift a `0` bit to the left without doing a negation at the end? For example, let's say I had a string of `1`'s and I wanted to move a `0` to the left by two positions:

```
1111 1110
1111 1011    '0' << 2
```

Or, is the only possible way to do this to do a negation at the end, ie:

```
mov $0b1, %al
shl $2, %al
not %al
```

Comment: If you know the high bits are `1`, the obvious thing would be `rol`, e.g. after `mov $0xfe, %al`.  `x<<2` implies shifting in zeros, but rotates shift in what comes out the top.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I see, so doing something like: `mov $-1, %al` `dec %al` `rol $2, %al` ?